# NodeMCU with a 5V latching relay - LOW triggers relay

Tags: nodemcu, relay

I am going to connect NodeMCU to a latching relay board like tis one (4 channel version): [LINK](https://www.wish.com/product/1pc-5v-12v-flip-flop-latch-relay-module-bistable-self-lock-io25c04-5ddc9180e799ac03db9d54d3?hide_login_modal=true&share=web)

Both MCU board and relay board will be powered from the same 5V voltage regulator.

Now I have two problems to solve:

**Problem 1** - logic levels

NodeMCU logic level is 3.3V and relays board works in 5V levels.
I can either use logic level converters or simple transoptors. Because I am going to attach NodeMCU to a custom PCB, I think transoptors will be simpler to solder.

**Problem 2** - relay triggers with low pulse on the control pin

This relay boards works like this: every time the channel pin (T1 - T4) is connected to ground for few miliseconds - the relay flips to other state.
Here is the question: **when the MCU board resets/reboots on power cycle, how do I ensure that the control pins are HIGH from the beginning?** If they are not, the relay can flip randomly before my program starts and I will not know the initial state of relay.

What would be the best approch here ?

Comment: How do you ensure that the relay module is in a certain state at power-up? The linked resource says nothing concerning this.

Comment: It seems that my particular relay board is always in the same (NO) state after connecting 5V power. So there is no ambiguity at start, unless some random low-pulse is not send to control pins

Comment: Seems High Impedance won't trigger. So first set pin to HIGH, then pinMode OUTPUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ports commonly are configured as inputs at reset, you will need to add a pull-up resistor.

Then write your setup so that the pin is high before switching to output mode.

**EDIT:**

Some microcontrollers have internal pull-ups, that are even activated at reset, see the specific data sheet. (*Thanks, Juraj.* I don't know NodeMCU enough to go in details. Anyway, my answer might apply to other controllers and other loads, too.)

The value of the pull-up can be determined by the maximum input current for the relay module (or your adapting circuitry) and the respective voltages. To be sure, make it a bit smaller, for example to the next E-series value. Just an example: minimum supply voltage is 3.15V (3V minus 5%), the maximum input voltage to detect "high" is 2.4V and maximum input current is 10 µA. Then the resistor will need to be at most Rmax = (Vdd_min - Vin_max) / Iin_max = (3.15V - 2.4V) / 10 µA = 75kOhm. This value is part of the E24 series, but is can be 68kOhm that is in the E6 series.

However, it [seems as if the circuit of the modules contains a simple PNP BJT](https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2018/08/07/re-inverting-an-inverting-relay/), a pull-up will not work here, because the input needs to be pulled up to the supply voltage of the module. You need a level converter, this could be a simple transistor. How to design that circuit, is another issue. There are lots of information in the web how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! This seems as a solving answer!
Any hints what resistor values I should choose? What do I need to know before choosing resistors ?

Comment: esp8266 has internal pullup activated on io pins at boot

Comment: use pins 4 and 5, they are quieter during power-up than other GPIOs.